# Rebind DOM Event with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

This is purely a theoretical question so I'm not looking for alternative solutions.

Is there some way of getting the default handler to do something like this

```
var defaultHandler = $("#test").click;
$('#test').unbind('click');
$('#test').bind('click', defaultHandler);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the default handler"? The default action the browser would take in the absence of any jQuery event handlers?

Comment: No - whatever is lost by unbinding 'click'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the `.data('events')` object, which is used to store all event handler information:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $test = $('#test');

    $test.bind('click', function() {
        alert('default handler');
    });   

    var storedClick = $test.data('events').click[0].handler;

    $test.unbind('click');

    $('#restore').click(function() {
        $test.bind('click', storedClick);
    });
});
```

See this in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/76GPF/

Remember, the `events object` is holding `Arrays`, so in the real world you should store the complete array information. I just stored the very first handler in this example.

Comment: I believe that is not what he is asking. He state very cleary `I'm not looking for alternative solutions.`

Comment: @BrunoLM: I'm not sure, in his example `$('#test').click` does represent the event handler, but a jQuery method.

Comment: yes, you are correct. That's the only place where events are stored when binding with jQuery. I was confusing with plain js.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for. By 'no alternative solutions' I was meaning don't say, "just declare the function and then bind/unbind it".