# Enabling jQuery contextMenu item on ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, contextmenu, jquery

I'm trying to update [contextmenu](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html) item if ajax requests alters my div content.

Here is what I mean I have a div like this :

```
<div id="" class="message" data-options='{"update":"YES", "delete":"NO">
</div>
```

And context Menu jquery part (this happens only once when body loads):

```
$.contextMenu({
        selector: '.message', 
        trigger: 'left',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "update": {
                name: "Update",
                disabled: function(key, opt) { 
                    return (this.data("options").update === "NO")
                },
            },
            "delete": {
                name: "Delete", 
                 disabled: function(key, opt) { 
                    return (this.data("options").delete=== "NO")
                }
           //etc. rest of the code
```

I'm looking to re-create it when some ajax request happens or disable/enable items somehow

So now some ajax requests happen and on success I'm trying to update `div.message` `data-option` because I though of enabling/disabling buttons like this :

```
In ajax.success function :
- disable or enable menu items
```

`--------Actually--------Simplified`

Actually this question/answer is very similar to my current issue :

[Disable and enable jQuery context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728957/disable-and-enable-jquery-context-menu)

I want to enable/disable contextMenu item on some button click, if I were able to do in this dummy example I think I could handle ajax request as well.

Comment: I'm having major doubts whether or not you should use the data attribute for this. I'm not sure if you could/should use objects for the data-attribute. My first impression is that values are stored as strings..? You could attach objects to the element with JavaScript.

Comment: what wrong with the answer you pointed to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `build` option to add new items, you can see that you can do with items here whatever you want: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Tvv4P/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="context-menu-one box menu-1">
    <strong>right click me</strong>
</div>

<button id="add"> Add item</button>
<button id="disable_cut"> Disable cut</button>
<button id="enable_cut"> enable cut</button>
​
```

JS:

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',
    build: function($trigger, e) {
        console.log(e);
        return {
            callback: function(key, options) {
                var m = "clicked: " + key;
                console.log(m);
                //window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
            },
            items: items
        };
    }
});
var items = {
    "edit": {
        name: "Edit",
        icon: "edit"
    },
    "cut": {
        name: "Cut",
        icon: "cut"
    },
    "copy": {
        name: "Copy",
        icon: "copy"
    },
    "paste": {
        name: "Paste",
        icon: "paste"
    },
    "delete": {
        name: "Delete",
        icon: "delete"
    },
    "sep1": "---------",
    "quit": {
        name: "Quit",
        icon: "quit"
    }};
var newitemN=0;
$('#add').click(function() {
            var newitem={};
        newitem['newitem_'+newitemN]={
            name: 'new item #'+newitemN,
            icon: "copy"
        };
   newitemN++;
   $.extend(items,newitem);
});

$('#disable_cut').click(function() {
    items.cut.disabled=true;
});

$('#enable_cut').click(function() {
    items.cut.disabled=false;
});
```